# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int' in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, average

```
   import re
    import csv
    import gensim
    import pandas as pd
    def processing(kata):
        words=re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)', '', str(kata))
        words= re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', words)
        return words

    #fp = open('data/data.csv', 'r',)
    path = './model_terbaru/idwiki_word2vec_100.model'
    model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load(path)
    data = pd.read_csv('data/coba_data1.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1") 
    hehe=list(data)
    #print(data.head())
    for index,row in data.iterrows():
        total=[]
        kalimat=row[0]
        vector=[]
        rata=[]
        words=re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)', '', str(kalimat))
        words= re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', words)
        for word in words.split():    
            kata=word.lower()
            try:
                vector=model[""+kata+""]
                total=vector+total
                print(vector)
                print(total)
                print(kata)
            except:
                pass
        jumlah_kata=len(words.split())
        print(jumlah_kata)
        #ok=open('data/vector_training.csv','a')
        rata=total/jumlah_kata
        #tulis=csv.writer(ok,lineterminator='\n')
        #tulis.writerows([rata])
        print(rata)
    #ok.close()

rata=total/jumlah_kata
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

the problem with my code when summing each vector becomes total and also when averaging it. when I declare as below there is no error but the results are not as they should be.

```
    total=[100]
    kalimat=row[0]
    vector=[100]
    rata=[100]
```

Comment: You need to iterate over each element in the list.

Comment: Please read [ask]. This question is missing a lot of things: [mcve], full error message, and actual question

Answer (score 0):

To add elements to a list, you use the [append](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists) method. To divide each element in a list and return a new list, you can use list comprehension to access each element of the list, and not just divide the whole list. Amend the relevant sections of your code thus:

```py
total.append(vector)
```

and:

```py
rata = [x/jumlah_kata for each x in total]
```